# How to estimate single event probablitity based on data of aggregate event outcomes?

Tags: probability, estimation

At a recruiting company, we have cases with $n$ applicants each, and each case may result in a successful recruitment or not. We'd like to be able to determine the expected value of a single application, and thus would need to determine how a single application contributes to the success of a case. We have data of past cases like such:

```
+--------------+---------+
| Applications | Outcome |
+--------------+---------+
|           41 | Success |
|            6 | Fail    |
|           18 | Success |
|            4 | Success |
|           13 | Fail    |
|            8 | Fail    |
|           60 | Success |
|           22 | Success |
|           31 | Fail    |
|           72 | Success |
+--------------+---------+
```

If we assume that a case succeeds if it has at least one sufficiently good applicant, and the probability for a single applicant to be good enough is $p$, then the probability for a case to succeed as a function of the number of applicants is:

$$
P(n)=1-(1-p)^n
$$

My questions are:

1. **How would I estimate $p$ from data like above?**

   Intuitively such $p$ would have to maximize the probability of the overall outcomes, like from the data above

   $$
   \max_p(P(41)(1-P(6))P(18)P(4)(1-P(13))...)
   $$

   But solving this from hundreds of cases seems so laborous that it makes me think that there should be a better way for situations like this, but I'm unable to find anything in literature. I'd also like to find some measure of variance for $p$.
2. **Furthermore, how would I test for differences in $p$ between groups?**

   For example, I might like to find out if there is a difference in quality between applications to IT and marketing positions. Doing the estimate from question 1. for each group separately would probably yield different values for each group, but how would I test the significance of that difference?

Comment: What "groups" do you have here? I don't understand that from your problem setup. Do you suspect (or want to test) that the probability of having a successful applicant increases w/ N, or do you assume that the probability of success is constant for all applicants irrespective of N?

Comment: @gung I assume that the probability of success (or rather, the probability of being _good enough_) of a single application is constant, yes. The groups would be different types of positions that we recruit people for, say analyst jobs, programming jobs, marketing jobs etc. But the most important thing is question 1, the total estimate across all cases.